# GoogleUser is not defined - Como solusionarlo?

Tags: javascript, login, oauth2, google-oauth

Estoy usando `Oauth2` de **Google** para inicio de sesión y no me arroja nada puse todo como indica en su documentación pero nada, ejecute por consola `GoogleUser` y dice que `(is not defined)`

```
 <script>

  function onSignIn() {
  /*var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  console.log('id_token');*/
  const googleUser = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
  const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());

}
```

Las líneas comentadas solo es porque estaba probado de esa otra manera.

Comment: no le pongas solucionado a tu pregunta, asi no funciona esta plataforma; publica tu respuesta y acepatala dando clic en la palomita del lado izquierdo

Comment: como dice @shadow: no le pongas solucionado a tu pregunta, mejor responde a tu propia pregunta y aceptala como respuesta.

Comment: Ok gracias. es que soy nuevo en la pagina y no entiendo el mecanismo.

Answer (score 2):

Después de tanto buscar y buscar por internet y no encontrar nada, tome la decisión de solucionarlo por mi cuenta y lo logre a media.

Ya por lo menos me arroja los datos y con eso puedo trabajar, tal vez no sea lo más correcto pero es una solución y la voy a compartir.

Espero que a alguien le sirva.

**Solo cambie este código:**

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
   var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
   console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
   console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
   console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
   console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
```

**Por este que programe:**

```
function onSignIn() {

    const gapix1 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    const gapix2 = gapix1.currentUser.get();
    const gapix3 = gapix2.getBasicProfile();

    const getId = gapix3.Eea; 
    const getName = gapix3.ofa +" "+ gapix3.wea; 
    const getName1 = gapix3.ofa;
    const getName2 = gapix3.wea;
    const getEmail = gapix3.U3;
    const getImageUrl = gapix3.Paa;
    const getidToken = gapix2.getAuthResponse().id_token;


  console.log('ID: ' + getId); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + getName);
  console.log('Name1: ' + getName1);
  console.log('Name2: ' + getName2);
  console.log('Image URL: ' + getImageUrl);
  console.log('Email: ' + getEmail); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
  console.log(getidToken); 

}
```

**Y el código del botón por este:**

```
<div class="g-signin2" onclick="setInterval(function(){ onSignIn(); }, 10000);" data-width="300" data-height="40" data-longtitle="true">
```

Comment: Excelente, muy bien tu respuesta.

De paso te dejo el enlace del [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que lo leas y este enlace directo que explica sobre [responder mi propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)